# The map $t\mapsto (\cos t,\sin t)$ is injective from $[0,2\pi)$ onto the circle, but its inverse is not continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

**Question:** given $\phi:[0,2\pi[\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ a map defined by $\phi(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ then

1. Shown that $\phi$ is injective into unitary circle $S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$
2. Find the inverse map $\phi^{-1}$ from $\phi$
3. Shown that $\phi^{-1}$ can't be continuous

**try**

for 1. i think, we have that for all $t$ that $\sin(t+2\pi)=\sin t$ and $\cos(t+2\pi)=\cos t$, then for $t\in[0,2\pi)$ we have that not exists $t_1\ne t_2$ that $(\cos t_1,\sin t_1)=(\cos t_2,\sin t_2)$ because:

$\cos t_1=\cos t_2\Rightarrow t_1=t_2\vee t_1=2\pi-t_2\\
\sin t_1=\sin t_2\Rightarrow t_1=t_2\vee t_1=\pi-t_2$

and $2\pi-t_2\ne\pi-t_2$, since $2\pi\not\in [0|2\pi[$ then we dont have twice times the same point since $\phi(2\pi)=\phi(0)$

for 2. i think it is on this way

$\phi\circ\phi^{-1}=I\\
(\cos t,\sin t)=(x,y)\\
\cos t=x,\sin t=y\iff \tan t=\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}=\frac{y}{x}\iff t=\arctan\frac{y}{x}$

then $\phi^{-1}(x,y)=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

Comment: What have you been able to do yourself?

Comment: Questions posted here should usually not be phrased in a way suitable for assigning homework.  It makes it look as if you're passing on to us something written by someone other than yourself without showing that you've understood the question.

Comment: I was taught to write the half-open interval as $[0,2\pi)$, and I've also seen it written as $[0,2\pi[$ (which I think of as the "French notation").  But I haven't seen $[0|2\pi[$ before. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injectivity loos rather correct. For the second part, you essentially want to "invert" polar coordinates restricted to the unit circle. The map $\phi^{-1}$ provides the angle $\varphi$ such that $x=\cos \varphi$ and $y = \sin \varphi$. Now,
$$
\varphi = \phi^{-1}(x,y) = \operatorname{atan2}(y,x),
$$
where atan2 is defined as in this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). The inverse $\phi^{-1}$ is defined whenever $x^2+y^2=1$, but it can't be continuous: if you approach $(1,0)$ along the upper half-circle, the angle tends to zero. If you approach $(1,0)$ along the lower half-circle, the angle tends to $2\pi$.

**Remark.** The function atan2 takes values in $(-\pi,\pi]$ instead of $[0,2\pi)$. You can easily modify its definition to get angles in $[0,2\pi)$.