# To prove $(\cos2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t):[0,1) \to S^1$ is injective.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry

Consider the map $f:[0,1) \to S^1$, defined as $f(t)=(\cos2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$; where $S^1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$. How to prove $f$ is injective?

I tried as follows: Suppose $(\cos2\pi t_1, \sin 2\pi t_1)=(\cos2\pi t_2, \sin 2\pi t_2)$ for some $t_1,t_2$. We want to prove $t_1=t_2$. We have, $\cos2\pi t_1=\cos2\pi t_2$, $\sin 2\pi t_1=\sin 2\pi t_2$. This implies, $\tan2\pi t_1=\tan2\pi t_2 \implies \frac{\tan\pi t_1}{1-\tan^2\pi t_1}=\frac{\tan\pi t_2}{1-\tan^2\pi t_2}$. If we prove $\frac{\tan\pi t}{1-\tan^2\pi t}:[0,1)\to \mathbb R$ is injective, then we are done. It is known from the graph of $\tan x$, that the function $\tan \pi t:[0,1)\to \mathbb R$ is injective; also $\frac {x}{1-x^2}:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$ is injective. It is known that composition of two injective maps is injective. But here  composing the two functions $\frac {x}{1-x^2}$ and $\tan \pi t$ is not working. Please help me to prove it.

The discussion on this page [The map $t\mapsto (\cos t,\sin t)$ is injective from $[0,2\pi)$ onto the circle, but its inverse is not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902025/the-map-t-mapsto-cos-t-sin-t-is-injective-from-0-2-pi-onto-the-circle) is not correct/sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $$\cos 2\pi t_1 - \cos 2\pi t_2 = 0$$
can be rewritten as
$$2\sin(\pi(t_1 + t_2))\sin (\pi(t_2-t_1)) = 0 \tag{1}$$
Also,
$$\sin 2\pi t_1 - \sin 2\pi t_2 = 0$$
can be rewritten as
$$2\cos (\pi(t_1 + t_2)) \sin (\pi(t_1 - t_2)) = 0 \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$, either $\sin(\pi(t_1 + t_2)) = 0$ or $\sin (\pi(t_2-t_1)) = 0$. If the former holds, then $t_1 + t_2 = k\in \Bbb Z$. Since $t_1,t_2 \in [0,1)$, the only possibilities are $t_1 + t_2 = 0$, or $t_1 + t_2 = 1$. Similarly, if $\sin (\pi(t_2-t_1)) = 0$, we have $t_1 = t_2$.

If $t_1 = t_2$, then we are done. Suppose $t_1 = -t_2$. As $t_1, t_2 \ge 0$, we must have $t_1 = t_2 = 0$. Lastly, if $t_1 + t_2 = 1$, consider equation $(2)$. Substituting $t_1 + t_2 = 1$, we get $\sin(\pi(t_1-t_2)) = 0$. We must have $t_1 - t_2 \in \Bbb Z$, which forces $t_1 = t_2$ as required.

Therefore, the given map is injective.